# nlohmann::json namespace error - even if includes are correct

Tags: c++, json, visual-studio-2015

I'm ntrying to use json parser from "nlohmann" v3.11.2,
I'm following the docs so I have coped the `single_include/nlohmann/* in my include/nlohmann folder

```cpp
#include "nlohmann\json.hpp" 
//...

//this throws a "intellisense" error: => nlohmann has no member json
using json=nlohmann::json;

int main (void){
read_json();
}


void read_json(){
// 
}
```

I'm on VS15 on Win10, building 64bit

Comment: Intellisense may fail sometimes. Do you really get the same error message when building? You shouldn't have been able to include the header, or I think you most probably misspelled the namespace.

Answer (score -1):

`#include "nlohmann\json.hpp"`  should be `#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>`

Comment: Thank for your reply, anyway it had no effect